# Redshift COPY from Parquet File interpreting JSON column as multiple columns

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, parquet

I am importing a parquet file from S3 into Redshift. The file has 3 columns. The last column is a JSON object with multiple columns. Using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE database_name.table_name (
    text_field_1 VARCHAR(255)
    , text_field_2 VARCHAR(255), 
    , json_field_1  VARCHAR(255));
```

Then I do the copy command:

```
 copy parquet.raw_jamcityads_purchase from 's3://my-bucket/my-file.parquet'
 iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::1###########2:role/R######S3'        
 parquet;
```

The issue is that the COPY command is interpreting `json_field_1` in the parquet file as multiple columns and gives me this error:

```
Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [500310] [XX000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: S3 Query Exception (Fetch) 
Details: 
-----------------------------------------------
  error:  S3 Query Exception (Fetch)
  code:      15001
  context:   Task failed due to an internal error. Unmatched number of columns between table and file. Table columns: 3, Data columns: 5, File name: ####
  query:     4384070
  location:  dory_util.cpp:872
  process:   query1_56_4384070 [pid=18317]
-----------------------------------------------;
```

I am not sure how to tell Redshift that `json_field_1` is one field in the parquet file.

I prefer to accomplish this goal with the `COPY` command rather than exploring Redshift Spectrum/Athena/etc since this is how we load our client data.

I would like to be able to load the JSON column as a string and dispose of it. I don't need what's in there. Right now, it's blocking me from loading the PARQUET file completely.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-copy-data-with-the-escape-option

Comment: Was this solved? Snathan escape does not work with parquet copy.
This issue seems to be related only to partitioned parquet S3 files

Comment: I think I found the issue, copy command for a partitioned data is currently not using the partition column in the folder path and since this column itself is it not in the data resulting in a load error of missing column